# Use subquery variable inside to_date

Tags: postgresql

I need to update my date with a subquery like this, i aint got a day number .

```
UPDATE grh
SET date = to_date('subquery.year-subquery.week_number','YYYYWW')
FROM (SELECT year,week_number
      FROM  grh) AS subquery
```

how could i use the subquery.year variable inside the to_date fonction ?

**TRY 1 :** So I've tried this :

```
UPDATE grh SET date  = to_date(week_number, 'WW');
```

And i have this kind of error :

> function to_date(integer,unknown) doesnt exists.

but if you look at this doc : https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_date.php

They say that WW exists, for specifiing a week number. My 'date' column is a date format .

**TRY 2 :** this is working :

```
  UPDATE grh SET date = to_date('42018', 'WWYYYY');
```

As soon as I try to use a variable like that, it doesnt work :

```
UPDATE grh SET date = to_date(string_agg(week_number,2018), 'WWYYYY');
```

Comment: Please include sample table data.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres( and most other SQL flavors ), the concatenation operator is `||`

```
UPDATE grh SET date = to_date(week_number||'2018', 'WWYYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked documentation on to_date function :
to_date( string1, format_mask )
and the error is 
function to_date(integer,unknown) doesnt exists.

so i think that you have a mismatch on the type of your first parameter

**Edit1**:
for the statement
 UPDATE grh SET date = to_date(string_agg(week_number,2018), 'WWYYYY');
if you chekc the documentation of the function string_agg you will see the expected type of input params are string and at least the second one is a integer